# How to add emphasis as with “I do” or “I did”?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, verbes, constructions, emphase

I know the verb *faire* means *to do* or “to make”, but is this the appropriate way of saying simply “I do”? For instance, if someone asks “Do you like it?” and you want to reply “Yes, I do.” Or, “Did you take out the trash?”: “Yes, I did.”

I realize I could just respond *oui*, but in English we frequently add *I do* for emphasis: is there a similar use or construct in French?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, as far as I know, there is no such construct in French. However, you have other options for emphasis besides variations of intonation

#### Using an adverb

Usually *beaucoup* or others amplifiers *énormément*, *terriblement*, *absolument*… As in

> *— Tu aimes les rollmops ?
>
> — Oui, **beaucoup**.*

One can also drop the *oui* in these cases

> *— Tu aimes les rollmops ?
>
> — **Absolument**.*

#### Repeating the verb of the question

> *— **Voulez**-vous porter plainte ?
>
> — Oui, je le **veux**.*
>
> *— **Mangez**-vous des rollmops ?
>
> — Oui, j'en **mange**.*

#### Using substitutes to *oui*

As *en effet*, *tout à fait*, though these convey only a slight emphasis in my opinion

> *— Mangez-vous des rollmops ?
>
> — **Tout à fait**.*

Comment: Great explanations and very useful ideas, thanks a lot!

Comment: There's also **repetition**, I think : _Oui oui oui_.

Comment: @Istao It sounds far less emphasising than *I do* to me. I find it closer to *oh yes!*.